# using parse to Like a post

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

in my app there is a function that is analogous to liking a post. In my parse database, I have a "Like" class. In the Like class are 2 columns, one "from_user" that is a pointer column pointing to the user who liked it. The other is "to_post", pointing to the post that was liked. my code is:

```
    var likeObject = PFObject(className: "Like")
    likeObject["from_user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    likeObject["to_post"] = objectIDArray[0]

    likeObject.saveInBackground()
```

For reference, the objectIDArray is an array that contains 1 element, the object ID of the given post that I want to like.

But when I try this, I get an error saying "expected type *Post, got String" which refers to the line of code:

```
       likeObject["to_post"] = objectIDArray[0]
```

So how do I make it so that the object ID of the post (that I do have access to) can be used to point to that specific post?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use a pointer to the Post class.
The parameter you pass to the `to_post` key should be of type `PFObject*`, but instead you're passing a `NSString*` (the object id).

Considering you already have the ObjectID of the post, what you have to do is fetch the PFObject from that id and set it to your `likeObject`.

Try this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectIDArray[0]) {
  (post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil && post != nil {
    likeObject["to_post"] = post
  } else {
    println(error)
  }
}
```